# Background-image for entire Ionic (4) Page not overlapping header and footer

Tags: css, ionic-framework, sass

I am migrating my Ionic 3 project to Ionic 4 and stumbled upon a problem with a page-specific background image which worked perfectly in Ionic 3 but not in Ionic 4.

The page has a image which should cover the full page, the page however has a `ion-header` and `ion-footer` component as well. 
In my `Ionic 3` the `html` looked as following:

```
<ion-header [ngClass]="'no-shadow'">

  <ion-navbar transparent>
    <ion-buttons start>
      <button ion-button icon-only menuToggle>
        <ion-icon name="menu"></ion-icon>
      </button>
    </ion-buttons>
  </ion-navbar>

</ion-header>

<ion-content>

  <ion-row class="logo-row" *ngIf="isKeyboardHidden">
    <ion-col col-8 offset-2 padding text-center>
      <img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo-dia-positive.png">
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <p style="height: 16px"></p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-list no-lines class="form-inputs">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="person"></ion-icon>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          [(ngModel)]="account.username"
          [placeholder]="'USERNAME' | translate"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label icon-only>
          <ion-icon name="unlock"></ion-icon>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          [(ngModel)]="account.password"
          [placeholder]="'PASSWORD' | translate"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col col-10 offset-1>
        <button
          ion-button
          block
          [disabled]="!f.valid || isLoading">
          {{'LOGIN' | translate}}
        </button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>
</ion-content>

<ion-footer *ngIf="isKeyboardHidden">
  <ion-row>
    <ion-col text-center>
      <p class="light-gray">
        <span class="bold">
          <a class="default-text"
             Some Footer Text
        </a>
        </span>
      </p>
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>
</ion-footer>
```

With the `scss`:

```
page-login {
  .content {
    background: url('../assets/img/background.png') no-repeat;
    background-size: cover;

    #logo {
      padding-top: 5rem;
    }

    form {
      position: absolute;
      bottom: 0;
      width: 100%;

      .logo-row {
        margin-bottom: 40%;
      }

      .form-inputs {

        .label-ios {
          width: 60px;
          max-width: 60px;
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

The result:
[image]

In `Ionic 4` the header and footer behave differently, for some reason I have to make the `ion-tool bar` `transparent` in the `scss`, and move both the `ion-header` and `ion-footer` **within** the `ion-content` to make the image overlap both, the `scss`:

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent;
  //--ion-toolbar-text-color: white;
  //--ion-color-base: transparent !important;
} 

ion-content {

  --background: url('../../../assets/img/background.png') no-repeat center/cover fixed;
  --background-size: cover;


  #logo {
    padding-top: 5rem;
  }

  form {
    --position: absolute;
    --bottom: 0;
    --width: 100%;

   // rest of scss..
  }
}
```

The `html`:

```
<ion-content>
  <ion-header no-border [ngClass]="'no-shadow'">
    <ion-toolbar slot="fixed">
      <ion-buttons slot="start">
        <ion-menu-toggle>
          <ion-button>
            <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="menu"></ion-icon>
          </ion-button>
        </ion-menu-toggle>
      </ion-buttons>
    </ion-toolbar>
  </ion-header>

  <ion-row class="logo-row" *ngIf="isKeyboardHidden">
    <ion-col size="8" offset="2" class="ion-padding ion-text-center">
      <img id="logo" src="assets/img/logo-dia-positive.png">
    </ion-col>
  </ion-row>

  <form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col>
        <p style="height: 16px"></p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
    <ion-list no-lines class="form-inputs">
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="person"></ion-icon>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input
          type="text"
          name="username"
          [(ngModel)]="account.username"
          [placeholder]="'USERNAME' | translate"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
      <ion-item>
        <ion-label>
          <ion-icon slot="icon-only" name="unlock"></ion-icon>
        </ion-label>
        <ion-input
          type="password"
          name="password"
          [(ngModel)]="account.password"
          [placeholder]="'PASSWORD' | translate"
          required></ion-input>
      </ion-item>
    </ion-list>
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col size="10"  offset="1">
        <ion-button
          block
          [disabled]="!f.valid || isLoading">
          {{'LOGIN' | translate}}
        </ion-button>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </form>

  <ion-footer transparent *ngIf="isKeyboardHidden">
    <ion-row>
      <ion-col class="ion-text-center">
        <p class="light-gray">
          {{'DEVELOPED_BY' | translate}}
          <span class="bold">
            Some Text
          </span>
        </p>
      </ion-col>
    </ion-row>
  </ion-footer>
</ion-content>
```

This does not seem to make sense to me, there must be a way to move the `ion-header` and `ion-footer` outside of the `ion-content` in the html, with keeping the image overlapping both? 
If I move both back out, the result looks as following, and thus wrong:
[image]

**UPDATE** 
The proposed answer by @Sergey Rudenko works to some extend, the background image is displayed correctly but the disadvantage is that the `position: absolute` on the `footer` does not pushes the `form` element above the footer, instead the form element is positioned above / over the footer:
[image]
[image]

Comment: problem is your are using ion-header inside your ion-content element. take them out and everything will be fixed. Same as the answer blow.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sorry if I am not fully understanding your context, but can't you do something like this:

Template:

```
<ion-header style="position: absolute; left: 0; top: 0; right: 0" no-border>
    <ion-toolbar>
        <ion-title>
            Ionic 4 template
        </ion-title>
    </ion-toolbar>
</ion-header>

<ion-content>

</ion-content>

<ion-footer style="position: absolute; left: 0; bottom: 0; right: 0" no-border>
  <ion-toolbar>
    <ion-button expand="block">Hit Me</ion-button>
  </ion-toolbar>
</ion-footer>
```

SCSS:

```
ion-toolbar {
  --background: transparent;
  --ion-color-base: transparent !important;
}

ion-content {
  --background: url('https://via.placeholder.com/150') no-repeat center/cover fixed;
  --background-size: cover;
}

ion-header, ion-footer {
  border: 0px !important;
  border-bottom-color: transparent !important;
  background-image: none !important;
  border-bottom: none !important;
}
```

Depending on your use case maybe not using "absolute" but "fixed" position etc?

Comment: The disadvantage of this solution is that the form element is displayed over the footer element when using `position: absolute;` on the footer. See my updated post for more details.

Comment: Hey @Nicolas yes this adds a nuance. But you could place form inside footer in this case or just use css to deliniate that. But agree its not as clean as it was.